# Grouping only match in regex

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have a regex that i'm using OR (|) condition to match because I have multiple scenarios.

I want to group only the condition that match but the .groups() return all the grouping of the pattern.

```
s = '  (123)   456-7890  '

pattern = re.compile(r'''^\s*[(](\d{3})[)][ ]*(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})\s*$|^\s*(\d{3})[-][ ]*(\d{3})[- ]? 
                        (\d{4})\s*$|^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})\s*$''',re.VERBOSE)
match = pattern.match(s)

match.groups()
```

The result would be

```
('123', '456', '7890', None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

I need it to be just

```
('123', '456', '7890')
```

Comment: Works here: https://regex101.com/r/eTkR3z/1

Comment: yes i know it works but when you use groups(). it's showing None type for the other 2 conditions

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```py
import re
s = '  (123)   456-7890  '

regex_pattern = '^\s*[(]*(\d{3})[)-]*\s*(\d{3})[-]?\s*(\d{4})\s*$'

# USING re.finall 
#   And keeping the first entry only.
#     If you have more entries like this in the string/text,
#     then you will get a list of them.
re.findall(regex_pattern, s)[0]

# USING re.match
pattern = re.compile(regex_pattern, re.VERBOSE)
match = pattern.match(s)
match.groups()
```

#### Output

```
('123', '456', '7890')
```